# MassTransit publish call hangs

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I've been working on setting up a producer to load messages in Azure Service Bus using MassTransit. The code sits in our .net core web api. My method to send is pretty simple and looks like this.

```
public class ServiceBusProxy : IMessageProxy
{
    private readonly ILoggerManager _logger;
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _endpoint;

    public ServiceBusProxy(ILoggerManager logger, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _endpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task QueueMessage(int userId, Message message)
    {
        await _endpoint.Publish(message);
    }
}
```

This code currently hangs on publish and doesn't return. I updated the calling code to use async and await as well. Configuration is pretty simple as well.

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.UsingAzureServiceBus((busContext, busConfig) =>
            {
                busConfig.Host("our connection string");
                busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(busContext);
            });
        });
```

Is there something obvious that could be causing deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels very silly but added one config setting and now it works fine. The host call has some config where I set TransportType to ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets.

```
busConfig.Host("connection string", hostConfig =>
                {
                    hostConfig.TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, had to upgrade my Azure Service Bus namespace from Basic (which doesn't have topic, only queues) to Standard. According to [Mass transit documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/azure-service-bus), only these two tiers are supported

[image: azure]